# Parse data from a shell variable and resuse variable with new data

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a shell script that I use to do a few things requiring an actual IP address and the DNS name (for readability to the user).

A user will create a shell properties file containing variables that will be used in the script, and one of those variables contains a path and a DNS name for a server.  It's setup like this:

```
PROJ="Blah"
SERVER_NAME="MyServer"
SERVER_PATH="/<path>/$SERVERNAME/aFile/"
```

In my script, I require the IP address of `$SERVER_NAME`.  So I have a function that extracts the IP address, but I need to substitute that information into the `$SERVER_PATH` variable and then use the `$SERVER_PATH` variable.  Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: What is wrong with `SERVER_PATH="/<path>/$SERVERNAME/aFile/"`?

Comment: @AdamSiemion the script is rather complex and during a part of the execution, a machine is not able to traverse the ip address from the dns name.  So I need to do the translating before it gets to that part.

Comment: ha!  Maybe it's simpler than I thought.  I can just do a `SERVER_NAME=$SERVER_IP` (from my server ip function) which should automatically update my `$SERVER_PATH` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was right in front of me the entire time.  I just needed to replace `$SERVER_NAME` with the IP I obtained from my function.

I essentially just did `SERVER_NAME=$SERVER_IP` and that was it. I made it much more complicated than it needed to be!